# Is this really a duplicate (object dropped in liquid)?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/480642/i-was-wondering-if-the-mass-of-an-object-can-be-measured-by-the-effect-it-has-on) was considered a duplicate because of a previous question titled "Height of Water 'Splashing'". However, the previous question only considers the height of the splash, whereas answers to the later question may consider a lot of different effects on the body of water, such as height of the produced waves at a large distance from the point of impact, sounds generated in water, and so on.

Comment: The one who posted it apparently thinks so, at least. The "marked as duplicate by Community ♦" indicates that the OP agrees with the closure.

Comment: @Chris : Does that mean the question cannot be reopened? I just offered an argument against closing the question as a duplicate. Some people may reject the argument and some may accept it.

Comment: No, the post can still be reopened like any other.

Comment: @Chris : OK, I have voted to reopen.

Comment: Seems too broad to me.

Comment: @JMac : But not a duplicate:-)?

Comment: No, I wouldn't call it a duplicate because it somewhat skirts that with broadness.  I'm not going to reopen though because I would just want to close it for a different reason.